# Automatic face verification with only 2 images

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

**The problem statement:**

Given two images such as the two images of Brad Pitt below, figure out if the image contains the same person or no. The difficulty is that we have only one reference image for each person and what to figure out if any other incoming image contains the same person or no.

[image]

**Some research:**

There are a few different methods of solving this task, these are

1. Using color histograms
2. Keypoint oriented methods
3. Using deep convolutional neural networks or other ML techniques

The histogram methods involve calculating histograms based on color and defining some sort of metric between them and then deciding upon a threshold. One that I have tried is the [Earth Mover's Distance](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~efros/courses/LBMV07/Papers/rubner-jcviu-00.pdf). However this method is lacking in accuracy. 
The best approach therefore should be some sort of mix between 2nd and 3rd methods, and some preprocessing.

For preprocessing obvious steps to perform are:

1. Run a face detection such as Viola-Jones and separate the regions containing faces
2. Convert the said faces to grayscale
3. Run eye,mouth,nose detection algorithms perhaps using haar_cascades of opencv
4. Align the face images according found landmarks

All of this is done using opencv.

Extracting features such as [SIFT](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/affine/det_eval_files/lowe_ijcv2004.pdf) and MSER generate accuracy of between 73-76%. After some additional research I've come across this paper using [fisherfaces](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/2013/Simonyan13/simonyan13.pdf). And the fact that opencv has now the ability to create fisherface detectors and train them is great and works fantastically, achieving the accuracy promised by the paper on the Yale datasets.

The complication of the problem is that in my case **I don't have a database with several images of the same person**, to train the detector on. All I have is a single image corresponding to a single person, and given another image I want to understand whether this is the same person or no.

So what I am interested in knowing is`
Has anyone tried anything of the sort? What are some papers/methods/libraries that I should look into?

Do you have any suggestions on how to tackle problem?

Answer (score 4):

Since you have only one image, you can give this method using DLib a try. I have used 3-4 images per person and it is giving good results.

- Detect face (sample_face)
- Get face descriptor (128 D vector) using dlib compute_face_descriptor (Check [link](http://dlib.net/face_recognition.py.html))
- Get the new picture in which you want to recognise the face
- detect face and compute the descriptor(lets call test_face).
- Compute euclidean distance between test_face descriptor and all sample_faces descriptor
- assign the test_face with class(person name) with least euclidean distance.

Give this a whirl, you can play with face aligning if you start getting good results.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the hot topic for computer visin area. To handle as you have written there are many kind of solutions are available.

But i suggest to look [OpenFace](https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/) which has very high accuracy. There is a implementation of that project at Github.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that machine learning doesn't work that way, there are intensive training carried out before your model can give some good results.

with the single image of a person you just cannot predict that its the same person, cause you need to train your model over different images of the person under different light intensities, angles and many other varying scenarios.

Still i would like to try this link :
http://hanzratech.in/2015/02/03/face-recognition-using-opencv.html

you may find some match for the image atleast.

Comment: I completely understand that you cannot train a classifier on a single image, the kind of answers I was hoping for were, links to paper where they train a feature extractor. Similar to Haar Cascades. I could for instance use the IMDBs image set train an extractor and then use it to my hearts desire.

Comment: I have given the link to hanzratech.in he has used opencv and haarcascade, i would suggest you either use opencv or you can try tflearn for neural networks

Comment: Thanks I have followed the link. I'm using tensorflow anyhow. I wasn't implying that you did not answer the question. :)

Answer (score -1):

> So what I am interested in knowing is` Has anyone tried anything of
>   the sort?

Yes. This is 2017 and facial recognition has been researched for decades.

> What are some papers/methods/libraries that I should look into?

Anything google throws at you searching "single image/sample face recognition"

> Do you have any suggestions on how to tackle problem?

See above

> Extracting features such as SIFT and MSER generate accuracy of between 73-76%.

I doubt humans, who's facial recognition is unmatched perform much better with only 1 image as reference. I mean I couldn't tell for sure if that's Brad Pitt or if one is just a look-alike and I have seen him on houndreds of pictures and hours of movies...